# Creating and appending dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which will give me a dataframe `olddataframe` as output in a loop, i want to combine them into a single Dataframe as `newdataframe` by appending and i tried the below code

```
newdataframe=pd.DataFrame
newdataframe.append(olddataframe,ignore_index=False)
```

it throws an error like below

```
TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

what needs to be done to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest create `list of DataFrame`s and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) only once, if performance is important:

```
dfs = []
for olddataframe in data:
    #data processing 
    dfs.append(olddataframe)

newdataframe = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works,but took a while to understand this :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `newdataframe=pd.DataFrame()` in the first line instead.

By using `newdataframe=pd.DataFrame` you didn't create a data frame, rather created a new name for DataFrame, so what you wrote was `pd.DataFrame.append(olddataframe,ignore_index=False)`, and your error is because the `append` function need 2 DataFrames, rather than 1.